# Any public accessible web service to get MedDRA description?

Tags: openfda

I used this api call to get reaction list:
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event?&search=???&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact&limit=24

I just want to forward users to a page that provides more description about the MedDRA term. But I could only find MeSH's website providing such information. So currently I just put the MedDRA term as keyword to MeSH's website.

demo: http://drugs.olc.tw/ingredients/view/54be8162-2d6c-45c7-94a4-5956d38a10d1

Answer (score 3):

Part of the difficulty is that Meddra is a licensed product.

http://www.meddra.org/subscription/subscription-rate

I am not aware of any place that offers the data online, since it is probably against the license agreement. At the top of the list is a minimal charge for non-commercial use, which might be a good option if you are just doing research.

Comment: Thanks. Hope the terms used by openfda could also become open data one day.

Comment: Indeed. A few small steps at a time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a MEDDRA offering available through [biontology.org](https://bioontology.org) via their bioportal. This allows you to specify the terminologies that interest you and make use of them via their API.

In use I have found that the MEDDRA server is useful for classification but has limits on the ability to identify the Organ systems that MEDDRA uses to group events.

Comment: Thank you for the info. It provides lots of results but may cause more confusing for people without medical background.

Comment: MEDRA is a medical classification ontology to categorize the side effects of medicines in a clinical trial. As such it is unlikely to be of much use to users outside the fields of medicine/clinical trials. I agree it is a complex site but it is a good source of data if users are unable to access via the MEDRA.org API.